# Installed updates bundled into ISO of Windows 10 created with Media Creation Tool?

Tags: windows-update, windows-10

Microsoft supports creating an offline installer of Windows 10 from a DVD or a USB flash drive, using the Media Creation Tool.

Does the Media Creation Tool bundle Windows Updates -- installed on the media-creating PC -- into the offline media it creates?

In other words, if Windows Update A01 is installed on my PC, and I create offline media on that same PC, then use that media to install Windows on another PC, will the other PC already have Update A01?

Comment: Check out http://superuser.com/a/957816/35525 for the http://catalog.update.microsoft.com site which will let you download the files seperately, but not bundle them pre-installed like you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, the Media Creation Tool will NOT bundle Windows Updates -- installed on the media-creating PC -- into the offline media it creates. This would be 'slip-streaming' but all the Media Creation Tool does is make the DVD/USB media bootable for the offline Windows 10 ISO file.