# How to download offline updates for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

It seems wsusoffline.net isn't using the same method as Windows 10 is using for their new update system, so I'm looking for an alternative way to download the Cumulative Updates for Windows 10 for offline computers.

Answer (score 2):

I see on the latest Windows 10 Cumulative update that there are two options, 1) Windows Update on the PC and

> Method 2: **Microsoft Update Catalog**
>
> To obtain the stand-alone package for this update, go to the [Microsoft
>   Update Catalog website](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3081438).

This actually allows you to download the installers for most Windows Updates, just [search](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=windows%2010%20update) for the update name.

You must use Internet Explorer to view these updates using the link I posted.  (I have to run IE as administrator even)