# How to get updates from a local PC on network?

Tags: windows

I run a computer refurbishment charity project and build Win 10 Pcs.
I need to download updates so I can complete the build process for a new PC but the updates from MS kill our entire business internet bandwidth (not just my workshop) so I want the new PC to get updates from a local PC (which is kept upto date) instead of MS.

Question1: does the new PC have to join the HomeGroup for this to work ?

Question2: Can I create more than 1 homegroup on a network as I cant seem to find out how to do it ??

Question3: Has anyone actually been able to prove if the updates download from a local pc ?

Question 4: I have read the MS Faq on Delivery Optimisation but it simple states it will look for other PCs on your local network", but does not state if it needs to be in a Homegroup or some other settings. Does anyone have any details please ?

Comment: I think a good way might be for you to download the updates locally to that one master computer (See http://superuser.com/questions/957815/how-to-download-offline-updates-for-windows-10 for a good start). Once the updates are downloaded, you can just put them on a networked drive, thumb drive, or whatever and keep that source updated. Make sense?

Comment: Windows 10 supports downloading Windows Updates from other computers on your network,they only have to be accessible, for that to happen.  All you have to do is enable that option.  Have you enabled it?

Comment: Thanks Eric, I followed the link to the MS catalogue using IE 11 but not really sure how to use the site nor what updates to download/store/deploy.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, Yes I have "Get updates from PCs on my local network" enabled, but I cant see that its actually doing it as the download speeds are about 5Mb/s which would indicate its not getting them from any local box.